# how to print superscript and subscript without using Unicode?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to print superscript and subscript using c#, without using Unicode symbols?

As a example I need to print Copywriter mark in my console app. i want to print it in the output console. my app is simple console application

this is how my code looks like

```
      Console.WriteLine("Printing the copyright mark  -  ©");
```

but it's only print the  "c" instead of ©

Comment: Console app? WFP? ASP.NET? Winforms? Please update your question with more info.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use unicode?

Comment: yes! when i use it it does not give the output in a correct way when i put the Copyright mark only "c" is Displaying but i need to print the © as it is

Comment: Can you provide an visual example of what the desired outpuut should look like? What do you mean by "Copywriter Mark"? If you mean the copyright symbol "©", you can directly type it with Alt+0169, or using "(c)" may suffice. Of do you mean Copy Editing markup symbols? Also, if you can type the symbol in MS Word (using a normal font), you should be able to copy-paste it into a string literal. `Console.WriteLine("©‡¥∞º");` works. Technically this is unicode, but not using an escape sequence.

Comment: Note that the © symbol is not a superscript or subscript, it is just another glyph like "Q" or "#". Superscript refers to *formatting* so that text appear raised above the normal text line, and often a little smaller. Subscript puts it below the normal line of text.

Comment: sorry for the spelling mistake its "COPYRIGHT"

Comment: @mbmcavoy, OP may also be referring to the unicode super/subscript characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Other_superscript_and_subscript_characters

Comment: Interesting - using `Console.WriteLine("\u00A9");` displays only "c" for me as well. However, as I mentioned above, pasting the "©" symbol into the code from MS Word does work.

Comment: Gaelan -  can you get the output using Unicode or simply Console.WriteLine("\u00A9");  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in the console it is not possible to print normal characters with special formatting. The console has no formatting.